# Import of PST backup of calendar folder is rejected as not containin calendar data

Tags: outlook, exchange

I recently migrated a user on Outlook with a pop account (PST file) to Exchange (OST file). We need to import his contacts from the PST file to the new Calendar in his Exchange box.

I added the PST folder back into Outlook and did a file export of just the calendar items to a new PST file. I then used Import to import that file into the Calendar folder in his Exchange mailbox. The import routine complains that the import file doesn't contain calendar data (the file is 5 mb).

I used this method on another Outlook user going from POP to Exchange with no problems.

Any ideas?

jpe

Comment: Just to clarify:  Are you trying to import the Contacts, the Calendar, or both?

Comment: Just calendar. Contacts I was able to drag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to open the PST file up in Outlook and check that the calendar data is present. If it is then you could look at exporting just the calendar data to another PST folder and try importing that.

Comment: Gosh, do I feel stupid. I was using the wrong PST file. In my defense, I was working (remotely) on a machine in Russian, which uses a different alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen occasionaly when a .pst file is damaged but I cannot see this being to blame as you have only just exported.

You could also try exporting to a differnt format such as .csv which you can open in excel/open office to prove that it contains data, and you can also import into the mailbox from this as well.

Comment: Thanks. Thought of that but couldn't go to CSV b/c CSV doesn't support recurring appts, of which he had many.

Answer (score 0):

I have a total hack ...

- create an account on Google
- Use [Google Calendar Sync](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=89955) to load the entries from the *old* account to Google
- Close up the old PST file
- Force the Google Sync to go the other direction

Comment: I hate moving to a middle-system just for the sake migration. It always causes problems in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Are we thinking the .PST is somehow corrupted? Have you tried any of the repair steps? TechRepublic has a good article explaining the steps.  Just google for "Repair corrupt Outlook PST files."